# Proving boundedness of a function (part 1).

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider the function 
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n) = \frac{\sum_{i}^{n}a_ix_i}{\sum_{i}^{n}b_ix_i}, 
\end{eqnarray}
over the set $S = \{x := (x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n):-1 \leq x_i \leq 1,\; \forall 1 \leq i \leq n,\; \sum_{i}^{n}b_ix_i \neq 0 \}$. Assume that the constants $(a_i, b_i),  1 \leq i \leq n$ are all strictly positive. Is the function $f(x)$ bounded over the set $S$.

Comment: What happens when you approach points with $\sum b_i x_i = 0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not bounded. Take for example $n=2$, $a_1=a_2=1$ and $b_1=1,b_2=1/2$. Then we can make the denominator arbitrarily closed to zero by taking $x_2=1$, and saying $x_1$ getting close to $-1/2$. Then, the numerator won't be zero, but the denominator will converge to zero making the function diverge to infinity.

Comment: Small caveat, if $\frac{a_i}{b_i}$ is independent of $i$, then it is bounded (constant).

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Maybe I am missing something, but in the example I gave, then $\frac{a_i}{b_i}$ is different for $i=1,2$.

Comment: Ooops of course, I just realized how silly I am, I was reading dependent in your sentence instead of independent :)

Comment: Thank you , the example $\frac{x_1+x_2}{x_1+1/2 x_2}$ is becoming clearly unbounded near the points (-1/2,1). However, i am still not clear of the other comment, that is $a_i/b_i$ is independent of $i$.

Comment: @Nubres If the coefficient vectors $(a_1,\dotsc,a_n)$ and $(b_1,\dotsc,b_n)$ are linearly dependent - that is what the condition tests - then your $f$ is constant (and constant functions are of course bounded).

Comment: What Daniel meant which is of course correct but I misinterpreted is the following. If $\frac{a_i}{b_i}=c$ for all $i$ then, write $a_i=cb_i$ and factor the numerator. Things will cancel.

Comment: Thank you, i did not realize you meant linear dependence.In that case as you say it is a constant function. It seems from the counter example by @Esoog, the function would always be unbounded.

Comment: @Nubres The function will be bounded if and only if the coefficient vectors are linearly dependent. The generic case is unboundedness, since $\ker B \not\subset \ker A$ if $A$ and $B$ are linearly independent ($A$ and $B$ are the linear forms $x\mapsto \sum a_i x_i$ resp $\sum b_i x_i$.)